# (Codenameone) Blackberry TextField Missing Border When Focusing

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-textfield, codenameone

I want to ask why the border of `TextField` in Blackberry (CodenameOne) always missing when focusing? I am using Native Themes and I have try with theme builder to change the attribute (`TextField` Background, border etc..) but still missing, does anyone know how to make border on the `TextField` still appear when you type something in the `TextField`? Thanks for your help
PS: This does not happen on LWUIT Thorsten Blackberry 1.4

Comment: Are you setting this style as "Selected" style? I hope

Comment: Yes i have set it, still not work

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly Thorsten's port doesn't use in place editing for input.

During input the native text field border is used, there is very limited control on the native input.

Comment: I straightening Thorsten port for editing text that has been used directly in the textbox, this time I ended up still using LWUIT for blackberry program that I created. Because the user I do not like the behavior of border codenameone lost focus when the user do (I've set the border style selected is still missing)

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say in that comment?

Comment: sorry what I mean here Blackberry LWUIT 1.4 is still pretty good compared to the porting of codenameone, there was a native menu, and the textfield is not a problem, I also do not understand why this feature is omitted in codenameone?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you were referring to LWUIT 1.4 and not 1.5. Thorsten's old port used the lightweight input which means that the native OS features aren't used. This won't work well on touch devices, won't properly support foreign languages and might have multiple problems with blackberry specific input features.

Comment: using the 1.4 TextField won't popup the auto complete list, to workaround some editing limitations in the CodenameOne BB port you can also do the following: 
`TextField t = new TextField();`
`t.puClientProperty("RIM.nativePopup");`
This will popup native editing box instead of the in place edit

Answer (score 0):

I have used LWUIT for some years in BlackBerry and yesterday I was facing the same problem. What I did:
Make my own version 1.5 using the things related to TextField and focus from 1.4 (BlackBerryTouchImplementation.java and BlackBerryTouchSupport.java and some little changes).

I did it because I found 2 problems more:
1.The textField were ignoring addDataChangeListener.
2.With constraints PASSWORD | NUMERIC in a TextField, the cursor doesnt move from the first place, I mean, you can enter 8 digit (qwer1234 because it's ignoring the constraints, input mode, input mode order) and the cursor is in the left side of "q".

I know that Shai Almog probably dont like it but let me tell you that I have made test on these BlackBerry devices: 9330, 9550, 9700 and all is ok.

I have been developing a big one app for around 4 months for Spanish language and the quality team have not found big problems.

Comment: I don't understand what I wouldn't like about this? The code is open source for people to change as they see fit.